# What is the difference between 'gaze out' and 'gaze out of'?

Tags: prepositions, difference

There are two sentences below

1. He gazed out the window.
2. He gazed out of the window.

What is the difference between the two expressions in meaning?
Please, tell me.

Comment: There is no practical difference in meaning.

Comment: It can be argued that |gaze out| is a phrasal verb and gaze [out of window] is a verb plus a prepositional phrase. The distinction is only important because there are sentences like this: ***They gazed out over the plain*** from the mountaintop. But practically speaking, your sentences have the same meaning here.

Comment: As the other two commenters said, they mean the same thing but the first sentence is better.

Comment: @Lambie, that argument is a bit of a stretch, as *gaze out* wouldn't take a direct object like that.  But it's worth mentioning as it's a similar-looking sentence constructed in a different way.

Comment: @TobySpeight It isn't a stretch at all because gaze out the window describes looking at something outside whereas "gazing out of the window" implies an inside space from which the gazing is being done. Practically, there is no difference but there could be a difference. The cow was ***gazing out of its stall as we went by***. Not: the cow was gazing out the stall. You see?

Comment: @Lambie, Do you mean "gaze out *at* the window"? That would certainly work.  I can't see any interpretation of "gaze out the window" that doesn't imply a missing "of".

Comment: @TobySpeight No, I don't. Repeat: practically, here they mean the same, they do not always mean the same thing.

Comment: @Lambie, so what's your example where *gaze out the window* doesn't mean *gaze out **of** the window*?

Comment: @TobySpeight They both mean that, one emphasizes what is OUTSIDE the window, the other emphasizes that you are INSIDE LOOKING OUT. See the cow example to see **they do not always mean the same thing**.

Comment: They conjure different images for me.  "He gazed out the window": he gazed in the direction of "out the window".  "He gazed out of the window": he stuck his head out of the open window and gazed.

Answer (score 1):

There is very little difference; one of them has a more formal register than the other.

In Britain, we normally use the preposition phrase "out of", and that's accepted in formal English.  In informal use, some dialects regularly omit the "of", and it is understood in context.  I don't recommend this form when you are writing.

Other regions appear to have this distinction reversed.

As an alternative, you could also consider, "He gazed **through** the window", but that is slightly different, as that can mean gazing *in to* rather than *out of*.

Comment: In my dialect, "out of" would be regarded as an artifact associated with a lower less-educated economic class.  *In that pitcher, I'm lookin' outta the window.*

Comment: Interesting - here (UK), that would be true of a phrase such as "off of", but "out of" is as standard as "away from".  I think I need to modify this answer in the light of your comment - thank you!